# Fragment inside Activity: OnClick not responding

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, fragment

I think I followed all necessary steps to achieve this, but somehow it still isn't working:
- The fragment's class implements the OnClickListener
- I did an override from the onClick event

What am I doing wrong here?

First I add my fragment to my activity like this:

```
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {


        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

My fragment XML looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="be.test.application.HomeFragment">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="be.prosteps.promoscanapp.HomeActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        layout="@layout/activity_drawer"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_welcome"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWelcomeUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_user"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtWelcome"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtWelcomeUser"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment's code is like this:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnTest:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "btnTest clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "other button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    button.setOnClickListener(HomeFragment.this);

    return view;
}
```

}